# Compiler error with pow() in a for loop

Tags: c, casting, for-loop, double

I'm a writing a function to print out a ternary tree in C. Of course, my method is terribly inefficient, but that's beside the point, all I need to do is print out the tree without regard to space or time complexity.
The compiler (gcc) is giving me an error on the line where the for loop is. I can't figure out what's wrong. I even set empty as a double, and I have included math.h, so I really do not see what the problem is. Please help!
This is the output from the compiler:

> make traverse clean
>   gcc -c -Wall traversals.c
> traversals.c: In function ‘printTree’:
>   traversals.c:112: error: syntax error before ‘)’ token
>   traversals.c:112: error: syntax error before ‘)’ token
>   make: *** [traversals.o] Error 1

Regrettably, it's not being very specific about what the error actually is. I think there are 2 errors actually.

```
void printTree(node_t* node)
{
    printf("%d %s %d\n", node->depth, node->string, node->counter); // Print the root node
    int level;
    double empty = 0;
    // Starting from the second level and ending when all the children of a particular level are null
    for(level = 2; empty != pow(3, level - 1)); level++)
    {
        empty = checkLevel(node, level); // Print out any children that match the requested depth level and return the number of empty children
    }
}
```

Comment: First off, pretty sure you don't want to use == or != with a double value.

Comment: @Mark: Why not? All the operations shown have exact results...

Comment: clang is a great tool for getting more specific error diagnostics for this kind of thing.

Comment: Instead of using floating point and `pow(3,level-1)` on each loop iteration, you should simply have an integer `int p3l=3;` and have `p3l*=3;` on each loop iteration.

Comment: @R. Really? What does checkLevel do?

Comment: @Mark: Read the comment at the end of the line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've got an extra `)`

```
for(level = 2; empty != pow(3, level - 1)); level++)
                                         ^ here
```